# Determine version of SQL Server from ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, .net-2.0

I need to determine the version of SQL Server (2000, 2005 or 2008 in this particular case) that a connection string connects a C# console application (.NET 2.0).  Can anyone provide any guidance on this?

Thanks, MagicAndi

**Update**

I would like to be able to determine the SQL Server version form the ADO.NET connection object if possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code will determine the version of SQL Server database being used - 2000, 2005 or 2008:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection));

    switch (server.Information.Version.Major)
    {
      case 8:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2000");
        break;
      case 9:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2005");
        break;
      case 10:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2008");
                break;
      default:
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SQL Server {0}", server.Information.Version.Major.ToString())); 
        break;   
    }
}
catch (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server",
        "Invalid Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

The code below will do the same, this time using [NinthSense's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73722/ninethsense) answer:

```
try
{       
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    string serverVersion = sqlConnection.ServerVersion;
    string[] serverVersionDetails = serverVersion.Split( new string[] {"."}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    int versionNumber = int.Parse(serverVersionDetails[0]);

    switch (versionNumber)
    {
        case 8:
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2000");
            break;
        case 9:
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2005");
            break;
        case 10:
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2008");
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SQL Server {0}", versionNumber.ToString()));  
            break;  
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to connect to server due to exception: {1}", ex.Message),
        "Invalid Connection!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
finally
{
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;user=admin;password=123456;");
con.Open();
Text = con.ServerVersion;
con.Close();
```

**con.ServerVersion** will give you:

- 9.x.x for SQL Server 2005
- 10.x.x for SQL Server 2008

Comment: The marked answer to this question is insanely complex, posted two minutes after the question was asked, and by the same author.  The actual correct answer to this question is this one.  Very simple one liner, as it should be.

Comment: I recently blogged a complex, but not-sql-server-dependant solution for this - http://blog.ninethsense.com/2015/09/get-list-of-installed-sql-server.html

Comment: @NinethSense link broken

Answer (score 8):

Run this script from a normal SqlCommand - it's quite extensive and useful!

```
SELECT  
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version', 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Patch Level',  
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition',
    SERVERPROPERTY('buildclrversion') as 'CLR Version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as 'Default Collation',
    SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
    SERVERPROPERTY('lcid') as 'LCID',
    SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name'
```

Marc

Comment: Marc_s, Wasn't quite what I was looking for, but very useful regardless! +1

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Select @@version
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: thijs, I could use this, but was looking for an way of determining the version information from the ADO.NET connection. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The Server version is also available as a (string) property on the Connection object and as a SqlVersion property on the ServerConnection.

And SQl2008 is version >= 10