# Get Output from my process

Tags: c#

I am querying the version of sql server using sqlcmd (from my app) and would like to display the info, say, on a rich text box, how do i go about it, here's the code:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlcmd";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-U sa -P somepassword -q 'SELECT @@VERSION' -S (localhost)\InstanceName";
        proc.Start();    


        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        while (!proc.HasExited)
        {
            q.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        }
        string r = q.ToString();
        rtbCheckVersion.Text = r;
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: why are you executing the shutdown.exe program for that??

Comment: oops..just corrected the mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect process output to System.String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829749/how-to-redirect-process-output-to-system-string). Actually this question (in various variations, has been asked a couple of times. Hint: with your `while (!proc.HasExited)` you are over-complicating things.

Comment: Why you are using sqlcmd, why not simply connect to DB and execute 'SELECT @@VERSION' ?

Comment: Hi Christian, you're actually right, it is sort of a duplicate. But how come am i not getting any output?

Comment: @Antonio, connecting to DB is too much work for such a simple query...

Comment: @coder16 Connecting to DB and performing the query yourself is actually much less CPU overhead than starting `sqlcmd`. I would say **"Redirecting process output is too much work for such a simple query"**.

Answer (score 2):

since you have to execute a sql script, you could use SqlConnection and SqlCommand to get the output instead of starting a separated process.

check this answer and other answers in this question for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/949933/559144

Comment: Thanks, Davide, great answear. but how do i get it right by using my technique?

Answer (score 0):

I see you don't want to use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`...
I'm not sure, but it could be that your process exits before you get output.
Try this:

```
proc.Start();    
string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: @coder16, you may also want to enable and read from `StandardError` in case "something" did not run as expected.

Comment: @Marco, got it: "Sqlcmd: '@@VERSION'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.\r\n" looks like my arguments are incorrect...